# JQuery: get child under cursor of a clicked parent

Tags: jquery, click, cursor, parent-child

Say we have a basic list like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

$('#list').on('click', function() {
  // how to get the li element that was clicked within the ul element?
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
$('#list').on('click','li', function() {
  // how to get the li element that was clicked within the ul element?
});
```

By adding a selector as an extra argument to the **.on()** method you get access to the element that triggers the event.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you won't want to assign click event to `li` directly instead, but I assume you want to do something with `ul` later in your code, so how about doing it the other way around?

```
$('#list li').on('click', function() {
   // if you need to get parent, do
   var parent = $(this).parent();
});
```